# How Might an Army with Modern Technology Gear up for Seal Clubbing Technologically Backwards Enemies?

Tags: technology, military, armors

In my book series, the Ishga Empire has a monopoly on technology that we would say ranges from an industrial revolution to sci-fi level, although their military tech capabilities for the sake of this question would probably be equal to Britain around the time of WW2. However, their technology is a very closely-guarded secret, with other nations' military tech ranging from just figuring out bronze to what we would probably call early Renaissance (derpy muskets and cannons but no rifles).

As a result, the Ishga military is a small, standing army made for the primary purpose of bullying larger but technologically vastly inferior forces into submission to extort land for colonies and "unequal treaties" out of foreign lands, not too dissimilar to what Britain did in the Opium Wars. What would such an army most likely look like in terms of armor and gear since they don't have to compete with anyone who could realistically beat them in open battle?

Comment: I would imagine that providing a _service,_ for example some long-distance communication or parcel delivery would sweep the world to their legs faster than an army. Imagine a company / state, able to provide telegraph / email speed of information dissimation. Or a modern-day delivery network with jets and internal combustion engines. All that in Victorian era or even in the days of the Roman Empire.

Comment: Seems like a chicken-and-egg problem: In order to have WW2-style capabilities, they must have a globe-spanning trade network to provide the steel, copper, rubber, oil, and other minimally-necessary materials for that capability. So those colonies must already exist in order to provide that capability.

Comment: Also, remember that the enemy gets a vote. After the majority of their army is slaughtered in open battle, the local prince will shift to ambushes, deception. guerilla fighting, bribery, information operations, inveiglement, and other methods of influencing the Ishgas that are more effective. The local prince may not know which methods are more effective at first, but they will keep trying until they find one. Nobody tries to fight in a way that exposes their weaknesses.

Comment: Fighter jets and aircraft carriers followed up with rapid-deployment ground troops are the typical means of bullying less advanced countries.  Fast, impressive, overwhelming, daunting and generally untouchable.   See [Desert Storm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gulf_War) for a good reference.

Comment: Which of the book series, the Ishga Empire is already in print… or is this actually "my story"?

Comment: Whether your Ishga Empire has a monopoly on the best technology seems not to be relevant to your Question.

More usefully, what technology do the victims have, that Ishga needs to defeat?

Without that detail Ishgar can either guess, or use its most potent weapons to guarantee success against all opponents…

Answer (score 18, accepted):

### "Amateurs talk tactics, professionals talk logistics"

A tank without fuel is a pillbox, probably in the wrong place, and a rifle without bullets is a badly balanced club. But they are operating in a very austere theater, as far as logistics go. Perhaps some of the enemies have decent Roman-style roads, perhaps not. That is more a question of social organization than a question of technology. There won't be workshops to repair a broken crankshaft, every drop of fuel will have to be carried in, etc.

**Air Force**

- Despite what I wrote about logistics challences, the air force will be important. Most of it will be what was called [army cooperation planes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Army_cooperation_aircraft) at the time, armed for ground attack but optimized for simple airfields. Almost as important are Grashopper-style [liaison aircraft](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liaison_aircraft). Some of them might be fitted with floats, or skis. No helicopters, or perhaps a very few for very special roles. Helicopters eat too much fuel and break down too often.
- A relatively large number of seaplanes or amphibians, like the [Catalina](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consolidated_PBY_Catalina). Or perhaps seaplanes with beaching gear (wheels to roll up the beach, not wheels for a ground landing). Some of these could be optimized for long range, like the [H8K](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kawanishi_H8K).
  *(As you can see in the comments, there was a suggestion for landplane transports. Possibly. Landplanes tend to be superior if there are enough high-quality airfields. My suggestion was for seaplanes because there are not all that many bulldozers in the army. Can they draft ten thousand peasants with shovels instead?)*
- A few aircraft might be very-long-range bombers and recon planes. They would count on being unopposed, so speed and defensive armament do not matter. Photo mapping from high altitude, daylight bombing from low altitude.
- Finally, perhaps a few interceptor squadrons to defend the capital against captured or rebellious air units. **If** they think of it, and if there is the R&D to do something better than the army cooperation planes mentioned above. That's a big if -- I'm writing from hindsight, knowing types that were not developed in isolation.

**Navy**

- Most of the combat ships will be updated versions of an 1870s-style [gunboat or corvette](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calypso-class_corvette). Sails and auxiliary steam engines (coal and/or oil, but probably coal). 12 knots under steam is more than enough, plus sails for long-range cruising. A few smallish naval quick-firers, plus secondary autocannon and MG. Mostly unarmored, these ships try to stay out of the enemy firing range. A good question if they use modern steel hulls or wood. How prevalent are shipworm and fouling in your world?
- Even more sailing transports with auxiliary engines. Less speed, fewer and smaller weapons and crew, more cargo. **Perhaps** a few pure steamers for express delivery of critical supplies. A lot of ships bringing coal to various coaling bases. Read about the run-up to the [Battle of Tsushima](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_Tsushima#Departure_of_the_Second_Pacific_Squadron) -- the Russians are often painted as incompetent, but look at their *awesome* efforts to even get there and be sunk.
- A few armored cruisers, to run down captured/rebelling gunboats and to provide naval gunfire to opposed landings. Against anything else they are overkill, and there will be few opportunities to use them.
- Plenty of riverine forces. Gunboats like the [Fly-class](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fly-class_gunboat), smaller patrol boats, lots of transports. Again a few armored river monitors. They *might* have to fight their way past enemy fortifications, with no time to batter them down with long-range bombardment.
- Cruisers and even gunboats might have catapult-launched floatplanes. They could be valuable for scouting. Also in the early hours of a landing, but that is a niche requirement.

**Army**

Almost everybody walks or rides horses (or horse-drawn wagons). There won't be roads for trucks in most places, and little need for tanks. The horse riders will be [mounted infantry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mounted_infantry#19th_century) or dragoons, not true cavalry. Usually they do not fight on their horses.

- The infantry and mounted infantry units get reinforced by armored cars. Light armored cars are armored against muskets, heavy crossbows, and the like, and carry water-cooled MGs with plenty of ammo. Heavy armored cars "should" resist a 3-lbr. or 6-lbr. field gun, and they are armed with light cannon (gun-mortars?) in addition to MGs.
  Armored cars, especially the lighter ones, might come with horse- or ox-drawn wagons for long distance transport. Those wagons *can* be repaired in a village smithy, unlike the armored cars.
- More MGs will be carried on pack animals, organic to both infantry and mounted infantry.
- There might or might not be jeep-style unarmored cars with MGs. If you go all the trouble to bring a vehicle, why not go the whole way and make it an armored car?
- Artillery are mostly [mountain guns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mountain_gun) or mortars on pack animals, with a few heavier horse-drawn pieces. Think hard if there are any anti-tank guns in the mix -- ground forces might be captured, and a horse-drawn gun is easier to learn than one of the heavy armored cars.
- Troops are armed with either bolt-action rifles or rifles similar to the [FN FAL/L1A1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L1A1_Self-Loading_Rifle). A magazine is a good idea in either case, and the rifle may or may not have optional automatic fire in addition to semi-automatic fire. (How often should they use *spray and pray*, and how many situations where it is tempting but wrong?) If automatic fire is not taken, then consider a rugged bolt-action design instead.
  It could be "something like 5.56mm" or "something like 7.62mm" or something in between. With aimed single fire, a magazine full of 7.62mm goes a long way, and it might be compatible with the MGs. But perhaps the light armored cars can be built to resist 5.56mm, and small infantry patrols could be ambushed and looted.
  (*There was a suggestion in the comments to use charger clips instead of magazines. Maybe, if the choice is a bolt-action. But I don't think the logistics savings are all that great.)*

**Railways**

Once they have control of an area, will they push strategic railways? If so, they will need forces to patrol them. Armed trains? Armored trains? Fit armored cars with railway wheels, to simplify the spare part supply?

**COIN**

Assuming they win any field battle, how can they win the peace? MP, Civil Affairs, PsyOp, ...

**WMD**

Depending on their morals (and desperation), they might go for poison gas, either dropped from aircraft or fired by mortars. Many of their technical edges will be lost of they have to storm a city, so gas could be the quick and dirty solution. Something non-persistent.

Comment: I'd suggest adding some transport planes. Some sea, some land—a landing strip for something like a DC-3 can be built fairly quickly even in poorly accessible places, so some could be set up behind the frontline for operative resupply of critical items. Plus air-dropping of supplies.

Comment: Although they wouldn't be up to sustained, long-term (daily) use by heavy vehicles, lower-tech civilizations did make good roads - roads that would be usable by especially lighter vehicles.  I'm thinking of the Romans, specifically - the primary limitation is _economic_, not technological, so it's plausible that more economically advanced nations (which would be the ones you want to bully anyways) might have roads you could use to invade, most likely between larger cities (smaller ones are unlikely to matter).

Comment: @JanHudec, I had thought of the seaplanes or amphibians in the transport role. They are not exactly optimized for airdropping, of course.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse, roads are just one part. When the WWII Allies came to Europe, they utilized local factories to produce spare parts. No such thing in a Roman-level country. For small, critical loads, send an aircraft. For big loads, keep in simple ...

Comment: In Pacific, on the other hand, Americans built a lot of resupply bases in places like jungles of Papua New Guinea, with absolutely zero infrastructure and only people with no technical skills around, that could accept DC-3s and medium bombers like B-25. It should be just as viable in ancient-Roman-level country too (most PNG was stone-age-level at the time; the operations even gave rise to the *cargo cult*, which indicates how poor the knowledge of the locals was about the outside world).

Comment: You want a gun with clips instead of Magazines to further reduce the logistics overhead

Comment: @Hobbamok, if you *can* teach your troops not to dump their magazines (except for a real crisis situation), you don't have to supply all that many. And magazines have more shots between fumbling around. Still, depends on the size of the high-tech manufacturing base.

Answer (score 12):

[image]

In real life, airships were not very useful in war because they are too vulnerable to enemy fire. But if your enemies have no way to shoot at them, then this problem disappears and they become powerful assets.

An airship is cheaper to keep in the air than fixed wing aircraft, and can stay stationary in the sky for very long periods of time. They make perfect observation posts. They can transport things, such as troops, anywhere in enemy territory. They can bomb enemy settlements at will. You can put a team of snipers into one. Or drop poison gas. The list goes on.

Their visibility can be an asset as well. When not running missions, they can simply float above the enemy capital, to give your diplomats some extra leverage during negotiations.

Comment: In real life airships could fly into flak fire twice, lose half their lifting gas and still land safely. Even compared to modern aircraft the WWII airships were the most resiliant aircraft that have existed. And that was with the overall bad designs and limited materials available to them. The biggest lack in WWI and WWII was their offensive capability when handling enemy planes. Even then the enemy planes had to spend a large part of their drum punching holes in a single spot, wait for the gas to slowly leak out and then ignite the gas outside.

Comment: Single, large zeppelins also have the advantage over any ground-based operations that the chance of some eventually falling into enemy hands is near zero

Comment: I'm hoping Airlander will bring us back to a world of Zepplins: https://www.hybridairvehicles.com/our-aircraft/airlander-10/

Comment: There is a quotation that airships did not perish in storms all that often because **few airshipmen were silly enough to fly into storms.** With a 1940s-era technology, and not 1910s-era, fixed wing is the way to go.

Comment: @o.m. The "way to go" depends on what you are doing. I've already listed a few things airships can do that fixed wing can't.

Answer (score 8):

**Death from Above**

WWII level tech makes it a vastly unfair fight.

The enemy can't fly but you can which means you can hit them anywhere and anytime and there isn't a damn thing they can do about it.

On the sea, simple gunboats will eat alive wooden sailing ships.

Your artillery can hit them before they can even see you so their cannons are useless.

Toss in some tanks and machine guns and they won't stand a chance.

For the final cherry on top, sniper rifles will take out their officers.

[image]

If you want secret attack forces, you bomb them at night from high up, subs sink their ships and snipers kill the officers from such a distance, nobody can ever find the shooter.

Comment: Add in the option for aerial bombardment using airborne gasses. Possibly even nonlethal, incapacitating stuff. Just how effective is a 50000-man napoleon-level army if you drop just a few hundred teargas canisters on them? Repeatedly, if needed. Every single time they pick up their weapons or start marching.

Comment: You don't need to engage the army at all. You can pop over the capital city and drop a "warning shot" on the royal palace/parliament building/whatever. That tends to focus the leaders' minds on surrender right quick. Going right for the head with superior artillery is how Britain once compelled a government's surrender [in forty minutes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anglo-Zanzibar_War).

Comment: @PcMan, which "the French" or "French Leadership" are we talking about? 1805? 1940? 1346? 2013? 1853? Thorne seems to see only one number, and that through a distorted lens ...

Comment: This actually happened, in 1920s Iraq. Not completely successfully. https://www.bbc.com/news/magazine-29441383

Comment: @o.m. Even in 1940, it was both the French **and the British** who were soundly defeated; the UK being saved only because of the sea. But by putting the blame solely on the French the UK tried to keep morale high; that was a way easier pill to swallow than "the Germans are very superior to both the French and the English" or "the English failed the same way the French did."

Answer (score 5):

While some answers are simple like "just mow them down with machineguns!" There are some important considerations to be made for your army.

- keeping your tech secret and out of their hands.
- once you leave your territory you have limited access to repair and maintenance facilities, especially if you dont want any of the tech in enemy hands.
- your army is small, receiving losses is a bigger blow to you.

This limits the way you want to fight. It would be easy to send out small squads with machineguns to destroy entire enemy battlegroups, but that brings immense risks. A musket-tech army that captures one such weapon would be able to improve their muskets, although the lack of industrial production would prevent fully copying the weapons. Enemies would also recognize that your small army cant be defeated with frontal assaults, but rather by splitting up into smaller forces and hope to ambush using the increased amount of soldiers available to them. Capturing even one such weapon and giving it to marksmen, wich already existed in musket area's, would also be a massive threat to your own forces who dont expect a peer-to-peer battle. Not to mention that the minéball era muskets had a pretty high accuracy and range, just lacking the rate of fire.

Then there is the question of what you do if you captured the area? People have to work in the supply dumps and maintenance shops for your wargear, those points would be excellent targets for guerilla tactics to capture technology and equipment. You cant build a lot of these.

This leads to splitting up the army in two forces: the shocktroops and the military police force. The shocktroops consist out of armored cars, light aircraft and the occasional mechanized infantry group with their higher tech weapons. The military police force consists out of one or two officers from your army with musket technology who lead locals trained and taught in your ideals armed with muskets as well.

The shocktroops are stationed in FOB's far from the local populace of wherever you took control with lots of cleared land so its hard to ambush them. All maintenance, repair and supply is done from these points, using the range and speed of vehicles to get around in the area. An explosive/incendiary charge is available in each vehicle to selfdestruct when it breaks down in inconvenient area's. These are just shows of force to take out any large concentration of forces and completely manned by your countrymen.

The local military police force with muskets can handle the smaller groups of enemy combattants and enforce propaganda to sway the populace to their side.

As an addition: the shocktroops have to be made to look like supernatural monsters. The armored vehicles are painted with eyes, bright colors and with fake claws and legs sticking out while speakers create loud bestial noises. aircraft fly with painted wings, monstrous beaks with teeth and shrieking speakers as they pass overhead. The idea that these might be manned needs to disappear, enemy commanders cannot get the idea that you can kill the crew with an ambush during their break but think they are dealing with demonic monsters that you control. The rumble of the engine needs to herald the coming of doom, to pacify the monsters you need to lay down your weapons or be destroyed. Psychology is and has been one of the most important factors of warfare next to logistics. Use it to make sure your technology is safe and resistance to your forces melts upon their arrival.

Answer (score 3):

My estimation is that such a group would be most effective as a very covert force. The technological advantage is massive - but of course even if you have an AK-47 in the middle ages you can still get killed by a volley of arrows.

So I imagine such a group of well outfitted warriors would be very secret, in supplement to a more conventional army that acts like a front. You'd want your secret band of soldiers to be trained to a high degree as to not leak weapons technology.

If this is all done right, simply saying "we're going to send these people after you" will be enough to scare anyone into submission. Spinning tales - and then confirming them, of one soldier killing a whole group of the enemy, could have a lot of power.

That is what you would want to focus on in how this army looks - how to get them in and out of a place quickly, suiting them for espionage. Basically, you have an army of assassins.

If you used them more openly, I could be interpreting this incorrectly, but it would lead to a mad rush to get your weapons technology. Your army however will do everything possible to avoid that.

Like how the US military has tried to distract people by saying that some advanced piece of cold war tech is aliens, your military might say that your army of assassins are capable of magic.

Fear and prestige will be the most powerful tool of this group - especially because you can actually show the force needed.

Imagine the power of being able to say "one of our men could kill a twenty men in less than a minute," and then actually being able to do so with a machine gun. It'd be the most feared military on the planet.

Comment: Magic is actually something that exists in this universe, it's just been 5,000+ years since anyone but some very insular orders of priests have known how to use it.

Comment: "but of course even if you have an AK-47 in the middle ages you can still get killed by a volley of arrows." If you're really dumb maybe.  The AK47 is reasonably accurate out to 800 yards, more if you're shooting at whole formations rather than individual people.  Longbows max out at about 350 yards.

Comment: @Ryan_L my point in the statement is that you are not invincible, and that if the people of the medieval world fear you enough, they will be able to kill you - if you blatantly reveal your AK out in broad daylight you will risk being taken out by larger numbers.

Comment: @WasatchWind At really close range, sure.  But why get that close?

Comment: @Ryan_L  .... again, my point is just that generally, you don't want to blow your huge advantage by challenging far greater numbers. In the context of the world of this question, yeah you could challenge a massive army and wipe them out, but then you'll attract the attention of everyone else, someone will steal your weapons tech, and you'll have to work quickly to ramp up production of your own weapons - which you would have to be building on a very small specialized basis for secrecy.

Comment: @Ryan_L Because not every battlefield is an open plain where you can see 800 yards in all directions?

Answer (score 3):

## Long range missiles

Missiles are, to this day, the *premium* option for long-distance force projection. This answer expands on [Thorne's](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/216005/41250) excellent one, and how that answer incorporates the advantages of some of the other approaches.

[image]

**Viability:** Missiles are well within the technological range of Britain during WWII. Though they were behind Germany in rocketry, they had Frank Whittle's jet engine designs. Therefore, either they could conceivably make jet-engine powered cruise missiles, or, if you trade their codebreakers and cavity magnetrons for German rocket scientists, you could give them ballistic missiles. The tech level is there.

**Secrecy**: Most of the time, there will be no trace of the weapon save for a crater. Even if an undetonated missile is found, it will be virtually useless to the finders, and, with proper tamper-proofing, largely fatal to investigate. Like in [WasatchWind's](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/216011/41250) answer, this maintains secrecy and projects terror, but without the disadvantage of having to put boots on the ground or expose soldiers or pilots to risk.

**Logistics**: As [o.m's](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/216012/41250) accepted answer points out, one of the major challenges is that you'd be operating in a scarcely resourced environment. You can't capture petroleum reserves from the enemy. Their roads will be crap. There's no factories to take over. So... don't *operate* in the theater. Launch your missiles from either submarines, airships, or place launch facilities in ground-inaccessible locations near your targets. You can resupply small, stationary bases by air without any issue, and be completely safe from retaliation.

You also avoid all the unpleasantness of having to be *present* in primitive, undeveloped country. For every combat casualty in the early Pacific theater, the US suffered *100* heat and disease casualties<sup>[4](https://books.google.com/books?hl=en&lr=&id=3r-_DwAAQBAJ&oi=fnd&pg=PR7&dq=Exertional+Heat+Illness:+A+Clinical+and+Evidence-Based+Guide&ots=XXOqMiHdzR&sig=tjk4u1VPSG5fgGHrKt2Y5ZA12YI#v=onepage&q=Exertional%20Heat%20Illness%3A%20A%20Clinical%20and%20Evidence-Based%20Guide&f=false)</sup>.

**Safety**: As user535733 points out in the comments, the enemy military can change its tactics to ambushes, deception, and so on, and allow for asymmetric warfare on a large scale. Weapons like [Punji sticks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Punji_stick) allow a four-year-old stone-age child to disproportionately harm a full-grown modern soldier with an assault rifle. Four-year old stone age children have a markedly worse record against missiles.

**Psychology**: As both [Priska](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/216034/41250) and [Demigan](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/216022/41250) note, the psychological aspect is huge. If you're preferred form of terror is the unknown, like the V2, you can achieve supersonic speeds on the descent, and there will be no warning at all before death comes from above. If your preformed form is *active* terror, then, by all means, float airships above enemy cities, and let them believe that those are where their death comes from. This has the bonus of misleading their focus: if the locals ever figure out rudimentary rocketry and take down one of the airships, wipe the entire city off the map from your nearest launching facility.

**Monopoly enforcement:** If one of the countries builds a university, destroy it. If the beginnings of higher level metal refineries are established, level them. If large masses of soldiers assemble, purely on principle, slaughter them. Missiles enable you to maintain your power in perpetuity.

**Clear upgrade path**: Even with explosives, you will have complete dominion, but by investing in more rocketry technology, in nuclear or chemical agents, and, eventually, in satellite technology, you will be able to continue to tighten your fist and establish control.

Comment: This. Sending troops with guns will always run the risk of something workable falling into enemy hands. With rockets, technologically backwards people will not even know what hit them (so you'd also need to have some doom-preachers in beforehand, so everyone knows this was you) - and even if the rocket crashes, it will be full of stuff no one can make heads and tails of.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is the [American 180](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J50N5lQoAFw).  This is a fully-automatic .22 caliber rifle, with magazines that hold 177 to 275 rounds.  .22lr is accurate and deadly out to 200 yards or more.  200 yards is far farther than muskets can accurately fire.  Small units with these and radios would be more than a match for much larger Napoleonic or earlier forces.  If they had helicopters for transport and good espionage to find high value targets, they could overthrow whole kingdoms with just a few hundred men.  Imagine Navy SEALs storming Versaille to see what I mean.

Answer (score 1):

Orbital satellites dropping tungsten rods. They can be as big or as small as your nation leaders want. If the science difference is that vast, there’s no plausible reason to ever have an open battle, period, full stop.

That means your opposition is going to be entirely guerrilla tactics, so you’ll be using spy ops and psych ops to counter.

But you won’t have much standing military.

Comment: Rods From God aren't viable until the 60's, about two decades past the specified time frame. But definitely the way to go in terms of methodology: strike from out of range, and don't maintain a military.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is almost entirely a logistical one.  And logistics in this case is almost entirely political.

In a pitched "fair" battle you'll be able to outfight the enemy 100:1 or more.  But that doesn't win wars, because the world more than outnumbers you 100:1.

You need bases.  Those bases need allies.  Those allies need to be kept in line.

Each base needs to be a fortress that can stand a siege by the local allies until relieved.  Ideally on the coast (which makes relief easier) with a port it can guard.  It needs guns large enough to demolish any attempt to position lower technology guns to siege its supply lines impossible.

Surrounding it needs to be an auxiliary base run not by the Ishga's, but by local patsies or allies.  This base is funded by trade controlled by the Ishga empire; the trade provides the funding and incentives to set up the auxiliary base, and the auxiliary base provides the resources and supplies and defence that the Ishga bases need.  By having local allies, the Ishga avoid having to constantly defend their supply fortresses; let the local allies bleed on each other.

The fortresses need both an inner redoubt, supply cache, and outer permiter.  The inner redoubt is intended to survive if the local allies are overrun or turn on them, the outer provides the area required for runway ships and supply storage.  Because the Ishga want to keep their technology secret, you have to have a way to demolish said supplies to being useless if the outer permiter is breached (or at least before the supply cache is breached).

This is similar to both the British and American system of bases around the world.  These bases provide fuel and ammunition to forces, plus a base for aircraft to be stored.

There are also going to be lesser fortresses which do not have resources usually in them.  These lesser fortresses are only secured when a fight needs to occur near them, and are otherwise mostly protected by the threat of retaliation and treaties with locals.  The short range of WW2 aircraft means that you need such lesser fortresses closer to the front lines of a conflict.

The Ishga will have deals that are profitable to the heads of the communities they have the tier 1 and tier 2 (and probably tier 3) fortresses in.  If the countries leaders are not interested in the deal, they are removed.

---

Military wise, horses stopped being practical with WW1 quality weapons.  As the enemy doesn't have WW1 quality weapons, cavalry with modern guns becomes a real thing for the Ishga.  Horses require less fuel and are decent off-road.  Dragoons, who use cavalry to reposition, and true cavalry, which fight on horseback, probably both have a use.  As a bonus, as "horses" is not a secret technology, you don't have to keep them within a secure perimeter; your client states can breed and feed them for you.

The Gatling gun was insanely strong in pre-WW1, and its improved versions and use in WW1 and WW2 made all previous tactics obsolete.  You simply can't charge a WW2 machine gun.  Machine-gun dragoon forces, where they use a horse to carry the gun and crew, would be an example of a deadly combination.

With WW2 level bombers and even WW1 era artillery, fortresses don't do anything besides provide rubble.  In WW1, huge concrete fortresses that where state of the art 10 years ago where reduced to rubble by their top-end guns.  Nobody with the level of technology the enemy has is going to be able to build anything capable of withstanding your weapons.

Now, such artillery is expensive and heavy.  So your forces will mostly move around with weapons sufficient to take out enemy fortification technology, not huge rainroad guns.

A bit part of WW1/WW2 era military might is the raw power of an industrialized state.  It is capable of mobalizing a huge percentage of the population, and equipping them with many pounds of personal deadly weaponry each, feeding them, and then giving them even heavier-duty armored equipment.  Firing off literally tonnes of weaponry, building railroads at faster than a walking pace, transporting huge guns on said railroads; that kind of industrial warfare.

Napoleon's Grand Army was 600,000 strong and insanely huge for the era; Canada's current army is only 10x smaller than it, and is insanely small for a country of its size today.  In the Renaissance armies where quite small.  To quite wikipedia:

> For example, the King of France could field around 20,000 men in total for his wars against Spain in the 1550s, but could mobilize up to 500,000 men into the field by 1700 in the War of the Spanish Succession

A "small" army by modern state sizes is a huge one by Renaissance standards.  It is only the inability to be everywhere at once that would limit your state; it could bring overwealming force to bear wherever it wants.  It could show up with repeating rifles, armor capable of deflecting enemy guns, trained horses, industrial state level siegecraft and logistics, and ships capable of destroying anything to the horizon in a matter of weeks or months anywhere in the world.

You won't be able to actually **occupy** the world.  So raw destruction isn't a good plan, except as an example to others.  Instead, you'd have local allies you'd prop up in exchange for payments and the like.

The lack of an enemy faction is a bit annoying; if your local allies are dominant everywhere, you run into the problem that their only remaining enemy is you.  So I'd suggest you *fracture* your state.  Have multiple factions of your Empire that play a game with the rest of the world, for political points back home.  It would even have a system to keep it "fair"; if you managed to win, you'd have to forfeit territory to keep the game entertaining.

This provides your puppet states someone to hate who isn't you.

Answer (score 0):

### Humongous Mecha

What, mechas are inefficient you say? Unreliable and expensive due to too many moving parts? Impossible to properly protect with armor due to all the joints and the huge amount of surface area? Walking is less efficient than driving? High risk of falling over? We should rather build boring, box-shaped tanks, because those are superior in every way?

Yes, you are correct about all of that. But none of that matters if you want to bully a technologically inferior enemy who isn't a threat to you anyway.

- The humanoid shape makes them look particularly intimidating. They are not soulless boxes. They are anthropomorphic representations of the oppressors. Literal giants towering above the oppressed, making them feel as small and insignificant as they are in the order of the world.
- They are expressive. They can communicate via body language in ways a vehicle can not. They can perform gestures which unmistakably communicate "I see what you are doing", "you shall not pass" or "get lost or you will be fired upon".
- They are higher than they are long. This makes them visible from a long distance, constantly reminding the oppressed of the presence of the oppressors. It also gives the pilots of these mecha a good view on the oppressed crawling beneath them. Like worthless vermin they can literally crush under their feet if they gave them a reason to.

Answer (score 0):

The other (technologically inferior) nations will adapt their strategy, taking into account their opponents many strengths. They will very quickly learn that a head-on assault leads to unsustainable casualties, and instead find alternative ways to harass and wear-down their enemy - probably ending up with an insurgency strategy.

> If your enemy is secure at all points, be prepared for him. If he is in superior strength, evade him. If your opponent is temperamental, seek to irritate him. Pretend to be weak, that he may grow arrogant. If he is taking his ease, give him no rest. If his forces are united, separate them. If sovereign and subject are in accord, put division between them. Attack him where he is unprepared, appear where you are not expected. - *Sun Tzu*

Hit-and-run ambush tactics are one way to damage the enemy without getting into a protracted firefight (where they can bring their technological advantages to bear). WWII era armoured vehicles were vulnerable to incendiary attacks, and dismounted troops would be vulnerable to black powder IED.

The Ishga Empire forces should adapt in response as well. Prolonged conflict that drags on in far away lands is unpopular domestically, but even more so when coffins are flying home, so they will be risk averse and keen to minimise friendly casualties. Their numerical inferioriority also means that significant losses will have a big impact on their ability to wage war, so they prioritise force protection over mobility.

- Soldiers travel in convoys of light armoured vehicles, peering out of small, thick windows.
- There are some roads, although they aren't in a good state and certainly not rated for heavy vehicles. Most Ishga Empire vehicles are half-tracked: something like an [M3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M3_half-track) with a roof.
- While technological superiority guarantees victory in a straight fight, it's a lot easier and safer to not fight and sometimes actions speak louder than words. Vehicle-mounted incendiary weapons (flame-thrower etc) instill such fear in the enemy that they surrender as soon as they see the pilot light is lit.
- Dismounted soldiers are wearing bulky steel plate armour (e.g. cuirass or [steel bib](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steel_Bib) on their body, with high collar and a full helmet. 2mm thickness should be sufficient, provided it is wrought to the required quality. They can't move especially quickly, so they rely on their vehicles for mobility. The armour is there to reduce deaths (injuries attract less political heat back home), and buy some time while they re-organise and bring force to bear.

WWII-era fighter and bomber technology evolved rapidly in the interwar period, but without a peer adversary it is unlikely that things would have evolved much beyond Zeppelins. As pointed out above, they solve the problem of observing the enemy, bombarding them, can fly out of harm's reach and require fewer resources to fly and maintain than aeroplanes.